# Size of an image with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to get the file size of an image with Selenium (in java)? 
I just created a project where I get all images of a web page. Now I also want to know "how big" these images are. Is this possible?

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setProxy("", port);
driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");

List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
System.out.println("Total images are " + inputs.size());

for (Iterator iterator = inputs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    WebElement webElement = (WebElement) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(webElement);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask the server:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(webElement.getAttribute("src")).openConnection();
int size = urlConnection.getContentLength(); // in bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! As far as I can see it, this works out for me!

Comment: I found an answer not requiring to load the image again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36296478/661414

Comment: This answer talks about image dimensions in pixels not the size in bytes.