# Selenium get natural height and width of an element. should not rely on style attribute. GetSize(), GetLocation() and getRect() fails to do so

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is the scenario.

When am using GetSize(), GetLocation() Functions against the image ID 'FlashID1x' its always giving 250,300 but the actual height and width of an element is 1 X 1 which is basically wrong.

Here is my target dom:

```html
<img id="FlashID1x" border="0" width="300" height="250" style="width:300px;height:250px;" alt="" src="http://s2.adform.net/Banners/invisible.gif?bv=2"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("total : "+iframe.size());  
//driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

org.openqa.selenium.Point point=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FlashID1x']")).getLocation();  
System.out.println("X Position : "+point.x);  
System.out.println("Y Position : "+point.y);  

System.out.println("X getX : "+point.getX());  
System.out.println("Y gety : "+point.getY());  

Rectangle pointer=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FlashID1x']")).getRect();
System.out.println("height : "+pointer.hashCode();
System.out.println(" width : "+pointer.getWidth());  

System.out.println("getHeight : "+pointer.getHeight());  
System.out.println(" getWidth : "+pointer.getWidth());
```

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to get the size of the image itself (1x1) or the size of the `img` element containing the image (300x250)?

Comment: What's the end goal of getting the size of the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The getSize method returns the rendered web element size and not the physical size of an image.
If your goal is to get the intrinsic height and width, then you could try to get the naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");

// get the intrinsic size with the getAttribute method
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img"));
String naturalWidth = ele.getAttribute("naturalWidth");
String naturalHeight = ele.getAttribute("naturalHeight");

// get the intrinsic size with a piece of Javascript
ArrayList result = (ArrayList)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        "return [arguments[0].naturalWidth, arguments[0].naturalHeight];", ele);
Long naturalWidth2 = (Long)result.get(0);
Long naturalHeight2 = (Long)result.get(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the size of the image itself, it's pretty clear from the [WebDriver spec](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#get-element-rect) that it's CSS that determines the `<img>` element's dimensions, the same rule applied to every other type of element.

I think that's fair enough. Your markup clearly doesn't match the underlying image, but presumably there's some justification for that we can't see. Since your element's inflated size has an impact on the positioning of other elements, it's only fair that WebDriver accurately reports *their* locations, rather than pretending that they're neatly tucked alongside a tiny square.

If you need workarounds: you could create a `getImageRect()` method with a special override for that URL pattern or Id, you could use an HTTP library to check the real image's size on startup and cache it, or you could simply hardcode 1x1.