# Does Selenium's WebElement.getRect() work on Chrome or IE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium added the [getRect](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getRect--) method to WebElement in a recent release to return information about the size and location of an element. It seems to work correctly on Firefox but not Chrome or IE, resulting in the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: unknown command: session/ee0ddaada8c9efaa4cd1e62dedf51bbe/element/0.7774730015224409-16/rect
```

Has anyone else been able to get this function working, or is it currently only implemented in Firefox?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing in Python + Chrome

Comment: It does work on Python + Chrome btw. Seems to be an issue with the command.

Comment: @RemcoW what change did you make to your code to get it working?

Comment: I never used it myself, I just tested it because you mentioned it. However I suppose you could use `getSize()` and `getLocation()` to achieve a similar result.

Comment: I hadn't realised that .getSize() and .getLocation() were functionally identical to .getRect(), I'll just use those instead, thanks

Comment: I have the same issue with Python + Chrome, it seems the issue is down to WebDriver insides as per exception:      org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed (ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute (RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute (RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getRect (RemoteWebElement.java:343)

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around for your issue. Use getImageRect() method with a special override for that URL pattern or Id, you could use an HTTP library to check the real image's size on startup and cache it.

Try this I'm not sure it would help 100%. Post me the outcome. I can get you the solution.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36295970/4163398) answer? If not I don't understand what you're suggesting..

Comment: Yes. Did you try this. It should work for your problem. If not, let me know I can find other options for you.

Comment: No, because that solution refers to a different problem. I have a workaround using .getSize() and .getLocation() but I still do not know why .getRect is not working in Chrome or IE.