# Web Element "Grows" After Being Scrolled into View

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I recently [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659625/selenium-webdriver-shamelessly-returns-incorrect-height-of-webelement?noredirect=1#comment112603946_63659625) on SO where I observed a different element height and width being returned by **Chrome Inspector** tool vs. **Selenium WebDriver** when calling `element.getSize().getWidth()` and `element.getSize().getHeight()`. With **Chrome Inspector** I get dimensions of `w = 979`, `h = 1961`. With `Selenium` I get dimensions of `979 and 1461` respectively.

Code I'm using to retrieve element:

```
String URL = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07G9RZD14";
driver.navigate().to(URL);

String XPath = ".//*[@id='aplus']/div";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPath));
```

I've repeated this experiment several times and each time I got the same result. [Some have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63667959/8814573) that I was changing the size of the browser however this is not the case. I always performed my test in maximized mode from start to finish.

I did experiment further and it turn out that if I inspect the element with **Chrome Inspector** immediately after the page loads (without scrolling down to element so it is put into view) the dimensions returned matches the dimensions returned by `Selenium` (1461). It is only after I scroll element into view that the element height "grows" to 1961.

When I inspect the HTML in the above URL I see a script executing an "expander" function.

I have three question.

**1)** How does this function work? (Looks like it's using `Javascript`)

**2)** Is it possible to get the real dimensions of the said element (1961) without scrolling element into view? Or it would be required to scroll into view element with this kind of function attached?

**3)** If it is required to scroll such elements into view, is it possible for us to know which elements have this function and need to be scrolled into view or I would have to scroll all elements into view as a precaution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amazon product pages are quite complex, and include a lot of lazy-loaded images and other elements. It's likely that your element is growing in size because new content is being rendered lazily as you scroll down the page.

To answer your question, you will certainly need to scroll down the entire page and allow all elements to finish rendering if you want completely accurate dimensions.